# Pattern matching vs. constructors

Tags: haskell

I have two almost equal functions for different data constructors and would like to know if there is a possibility to unify both. A minimalistic example would be the following

```
f_maybe :: Maybe a -> a -> a
f_maybe (Just x) _ = x
f_maybe _        x = x
```

and

```
data T a = T1 a | T2 Int | T3

f_t :: T a -> a -> a
f_t  (T1 x) _ = x
f_t  _      x = x
```

Is the a way to define only one function parametrized by the type constructors (Maybe or T) and the data constructor (Just or T1) doing both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a unified function that has any behavior you want and works on any
type of argument, but you cannot pattern match without concrete data
constructor (polymorphicly), AFAIK.

---

Ask yourself what type signature of this unified function would look like?
The type signature represents idea behind function. What do `Maybe` and `T`
have in common in this case so that you what to unify functions that work on
them? What kind of abstraction are you trying to build?

All these things are not clear from your question. If your idea is to just
cut boilerplate (and this is not exactly *boilerplate*), then do not try to
unify things that are different just to make code shorter, you will get
something confusing in the end.

Types actually should be different and functions should reject arguments of
wrong type, not work on anything that looks remotely similar. Too
polymorphic code is often not a good idea, because wrong code may happen to
have some meaning for type checker and then you will get program that
compiles, but does wrong things.

Comment: I afraid you are right - different constructors from different types can not directly be unified...

Answer (score 6):

Once you implemented `Foldable` instance for your data type, this idea can be expressed as `foldr const`.

```
data T a = T1 a | T2 Int | T3

instance Foldable T where
    -- if it's T1, it has a value
    foldMap f (T1 a) = f a
    -- if it's T2 or T3, it's considered "empty"
    foldMap f (T2 _) = mempty
    foldMap f T3     = mempty
```

You can even let `generic-deriving` package derive the above `Foldable` instance for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import           Generics.Deriving.Foldable
import           GHC.Generics

data T a = T1 a | T2 Int | T3
    deriving (Generic1)

instance Foldable T where
    foldMap = gfoldMapdefault
```

(In your case the instance is not ambiguous since only one of the constructors may contain exactly one value of type `a`. if the data type gets over-complicated with multiple constructors containing one or more `a`, you'd better do it manually or check carefully what that package derived)

And some results from ghci:

```
-- `Maybe` already has the instance defined by the standard library
> foldr const 2 (Just 3)
< 3
> foldr const 2 Nothing
< 2

> foldr const 2 (T1 3)
< 3
> foldr const 2 (T2 10)
< 2
> foldr const 2 T3
< 2
```

Comment: In general, the idea is to define a typeclass that both types implement; `Foldable` just happens to be the typeclass that works for the example function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like this implementation using foldables :)! Nevertheless, this was only a minimalistic example and I am not sure if the same works for the real one (relies on pattern matching).

Answer (score 3):

In order to satisfy your needs, both types need to share a common interface through a type class. It could be done like this:

```
class MyF mf where
    f :: mf a -> a -> a

instance MyF Maybe where
    f (Just x) _ = x
    f _        x = x

instance MyF T where
    f (T1 x) _ = x
    f _      x = x
```

Examples:

```
f (Just 3) 3
3

f Nothing "Hello"
"Hello"

f (T1 5) 3
5

f (T2 20) 2
2
```

Comment: You are right. I also though about a type class. But this way essentially the two different different definitions are used again.